# how to set ctex font size to \lishu

Tags: ctex

[log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BjGNUq6m4YaV6DEJNU_rl1G2wGM1g8-u/view?usp=sharing) I probably should spend more time getting to read the documentation but I must admit it is too advanced and I have a hard time comprehending what its tring to say.I am on a deadline and need some urgent help. What I want to achieve is to change the title style(font?) to \lishu as described in [ctex package](https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CTAN/language/chinese/ctex/ctex.pdf) page 8

This is my code

```
\documentclass[fontset=none]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\ctexset{fontset=macnew}
\begin{document}
\lishu
\title{颠覆传统教学模式，打造中国双师品牌}
\date{}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

But it results in an error saying "undefined control sequence."  Please tell me what went wrong here.This is the [cnosole feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpBEN.png)

Edit: new log file after updating it to texlive 2020[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ds4cHKf8wnb1rvppLsYnyHqFgxXPVzlS/view?usp=sharing)
edit2:uploaded the result of xetex compile. the link is the same.

Comment: I'm very upset with CTeX that advertises “fontset=macnew”, which should work in macOS, if I interpret correctly the name. But it doesn't. If I use `fontset=windows`, then I get an error because `simli.ttf` is not found.

Comment: I don't have a mac but based on the code the command should be defined. Is your ctex/tex system up-to-date? Can you show the log-file?

Comment: The command `\lishu` is not defined with `fontset=macnew` until `ctex` v2.5. From the attached log file, you are using `ctex` v2.4.15. Prior to v2.5, `\lishu` is defined with `fontset=windows|founder` only. See related issues (in Chinese): https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/issues/360 and https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/issues/412

Comment: Use `xelatex`, not `pdflatex`

Answer (score 2):

I can ensure you I'm on a Mac, running the latest version of macOS.

If I try your code, I get

```latex
! Critical Package ctex Error: CTeX fontset `mac' is unavailable in current
(ctex)                         mode.
```

which is quite strange. If I change `fontset=windows`, that error disappears, but `pdftex` complains that `simli.ttf` is not found.

So I downloaded `simli.ttf` from https://github.com/dudongtai2002/Font/blob/master/Fonts/SIMLI.TTF and retried.

```
\documentclass[fontset=windows]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\begin{document}
\title{\lishu 这是一个标题}
\date{}
\maketitle

这是一个标题

\end{document}
```

I used `\lishu` only inside the title, which is probably what you really want.

---

Now that you added the information that you're running XeLaTeX, the code above runs also with `fontset=macnew` (no download necessary). Also your code runs with no issue on TeX Live 2020.

I get the error is with TeX Live 2019, for the simple reason that `\lishu` is only available in `ctex-fontset-macnew.def` version 2.5.1 or later. See

http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/fontset/ctex-fontset-macnew.def?r1=51262&r2=54976

Comment: Would you be kind enough to tell me how to check my texlive version. I clicked the texlive utility page and it says Version 1.35

Comment: @jxhyc Install the [new MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex). You can see that the log file lists files as belonging to the tree `/usr/local/texlive/2019`

Comment: Thanks! I will choose the answer after I test your recommendation. It is a very large download:(

Comment: sorry doesn't work. :(

Comment: @jxhyc Which engine do you want to use? The first log shows xelatex, but the second log shows pdflatex.

Comment: Both fail to compile. I have reuploaded a  log file of xetex version

Answer (score 0):

- With `fontset=macnew`, `\lishu` is not defined until `ctex` v2.5.
- To install `ctex` v2.5, TeX Live 2020 is required, but from the attached log you are using TeX Live 2019.
- Hence you can either install TeX Live 2020, or manually define `\lishu` as following:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \lishu {} {\CJKfamily{zhli}}
\setCJKfamilyfont {zhli} {Baoli SC}
```

On macOS, Baoli SC is one of "available for download" fonts. Hence to use it for the first time, a window will pop up to ask for downloading. Just click "Download", and recompile tex file when the downloading is finished.